# What difference occurs when using the method defined using the prototype property of an object with the new keyword

Tags: javascript

My code works when I use my first case. Then I wondered about the second case. When the button is clicked, this.x and this.y values ​​are `undefined`

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ObjectKavrami.js">
</script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="demoObjectPrototype" onclick="onObjectWithPrototype()">JavaScript Object</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Case 1: returns "115":

```
var areaCalc = function(x,y) {
    this.x = x ;
    this.y = y ;
} 
areaCalc .prototype = {
        area: function() { return (this.x * this.y); }
}
var newarea = new areaCalc (5,23);

function onObjectWithPrototype () {
     alert(newarea .area());
 }
```

Case 2: returns `NaN`

```
var areaCalc = function(x,y) {
    this.x = x ;
    this.y = y ;
} 
areaCalc .prototype = {
        area: function() { return (this.x * this.y); }
}
//var newarea = new areaCalc (5,23);

function onObjectWithPrototype () {
     areaCalc(2,3);
     alert(areaCalc.prototype.area());
     //alert(newarea .area());
 }
```

Why can't the method see x and y values?

Comment: Primarily because `this` inside `area()` will be the `prototype` object, because `this` is always what appears before the last `.`. Secondarily because this is simply not how it's supposed to be used.

Comment: I wondered why ı need new object ? For that ı use second case . İf area is a property of areaCalc why I can not see x and y values

Answer (score 0):

The major reason behind this behavior is that new keyword binds the prototype object with the variable. So in your first case when you used area = new areaCalc(5,23)  the prototype object was binded with help of new keyword and thus when used this keyword inside prototype object it associates with the object that is invoking it.
But in the second case the prototype object was not associated with any object . This is the reason  why it gave such behavior.

Comment: Not sure if you're just explaining it in a misleading way, but the prototype object doesn't "bind" with the created object as such…